# Regular Expression for Mathjax string

Tags: java, regex

Any body give a solution for how to remove `mathjax` in a string using regular expression. For example my input string is

"Which sentence explains why the slope of `$!\overline{AB}!$` is equal to the slope of `$!\overline{BC}!$?`", what I'm expect is "Which sentence explains why the slope of is equal to the slope of?"

Comment: You can do `yourstring.replaceAll("$!.*!$","");`

Comment: It is not working for me gurwinder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\$!.*?!\$
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/y2Qu9N/1)

Sample Code

```
    final String regex = "\\$!.*?!\\$";
    final String string = "Which sentence explains why the slope of $!\\overline{AB}!$ is equal to the slope of $!\\overline{BC}!$?";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    final String result = matcher.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(result);
```